# phonegap logcat error external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:213:

Tags: android, cordova

keep getting error in logcat

```
02-18 12:13:00.849: E/chromium(6915): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:213: 
[0218/121300:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(213)] StatHub::Init - App  isn't supported.
```

App is still working though but want to know what is causing this error and will it be a issue

update: the google map script is causing the error

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCh2vwRCwkFWuEy8q-wbTF9vGobuyXC5G0&sensor=false"></script>
```

tried to put this in config.xml

```
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
```

still doesn't work and getting a

```
Application Error
The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```

Comment: Did you try removing the google maps script and see if the page(index.html) load ok.

Comment: yep google map is causing this tried to remove it and the error disappears

Comment: I am getting this same error in Android Game made using Unity3D. Does anyone know how can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using wildcards for subdomains currently isn't working.  I recommend doing the following instead:

```
<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true" />
```

I'm going to add a bug to the issue tracker to get this issue fixed.  It seems that we lost some regex logic when we pulled the configuration to its own class.